# Significance of closedness of a subspace when writing a Hilbert space as a direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I [read that](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hilbert_space) *if* $U$ is a *closed* subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ *then* we can write $H$ as $H = U \oplus U^\bot$ (the direct sum).

What is not clear to me is why $U$ is required to be closed. I thought about it but in finite dimension of course every subspace is closed so that was not helpful to me.

> What happens if $U$ is not closed? Why can we not write $H=U \oplus
>  U^\bot$ in that case?

(This question arose while I was trying to prove that $U^{\bot\bot}=U$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to see what can go wrong is to find a counterexample.  The easiest counterexample I can think of here is $\ell^2$.

Let $c_0 \subset \ell^2$ denote the set of sequences $(x_j)$ such that there exists an $n \in N$ such that $x_j = 0$ whenever $j \geq N$.  That is, let $c_0$ denote the set of all "terminating" sequences.

What is $(c_0)^\perp$? Is is clear now that $\ell^2 \neq (c_0) \oplus (c_0)^\perp$?

As a general note: keep in mind that $U^\perp = (\overline{U})^\perp$. To answer your original question then, we have $U^ {\perp\perp} = \overline U$.

Comment: I need a moment to think about what $c_0^\bot$ could be...

Comment: Take your time.  Is it clear to you that $c_0$ is, in fact, a subspace?

Comment: I am having trouble with this. If I think about an arbitrary sequence $a=a_n$ and conditions for which $\langle a,c\rangle=0$ for all $c\in c_0$ then I get that $a=0$. But this would mean that $c_0^\bot = 0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong. $(c_0)^\perp = \{0\}$.